# How to rotate Image in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, rotation

I want to rotate fan image when click the turnOn button.
And the turnOff button is clicked, rotation is stopped.

My code is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

  <img id="myFan" src="fan.png" width="200" heigh="100"><br>
  <button onclick="turnOn()"> On </button><br>
  <button onclick="turnOff()"> Off </button>

  <script>
    function turnOn() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myFan");
    }

    function turnOff() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myFan");
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: you need rotation in form of animation?

Comment: Yes. Like real fan.

Comment: Using CSS animations will be a great start to achieve your goal. There will be a lot of answers online if this is sought after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this (for some reason the image is not showing up):

```js
let timer;
let turn = 0;
function turnOn() {
  timer = setInterval(turnFan, 200);
  let x = document.getElementById("on");
  x.disabled = true;
}

function turnOff() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  let x = document.getElementById("on");
  x.disabled = false;
}

function turnFan() {
  let x = document.getElementById("myFan");
  turn += 60;
  x.style.transform = "rotate("+ (turn % 360) +"deg)"
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

  <img id="myFan" src="http://www.pngmart.com/files/7/Ceiling-Fan-PNG-Transparent-Image.png" width="200" heigh="100"><br>
  <button id="on" onclick="turnOn()"> On </button><br>
  <button id="off" onclick="turnOff()"> Off </button>

  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! You helped me a lot.

Comment: No problem. Could you accept my answer? i.e. the green tick

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented this in one of my projects:

```
function rotate90 (img){
var img=this

if (img.style.transform == ""){var x=90;
    window.localStorage.setItem("x", Number(x))  
}

else{
    var x = Number(window.localStorage.getItem("x"))
    x += 90;
    if (x==360){x=0}
    window.localStorage.setItem("x", Number(x))  
    }
img.style.transform ="rotate("+x+"deg)";

                    }
```

in your code use `img.onclick=rotate90;` It should work.

Answer (score 1):

### Using CSS Animations and `animation-play-state`

You can use a CSS animation to easily, continuously, and performantly rotate your image. In order to keep the animation from playing right away, you can set the `animation-play-state` CSS property to `paused`. When you want to make the animation play — to make the fan rotate — you can either unset `animation-play-state` or set it to `running`.

#### How do I make this accessible

You can set the `alt` attribute on the image according to what it looks like to the user (i.e. spinning or not). To let the user know if this change, you should set `aria-live="polite"` so that the assistive technology will read aloud the alternative text.

In order to make the on/off buttons more accessible, you have a few options. One option would be to set `display: none` on the button that was last pressed. Another option would be to set `disabled` to `true` on the last pressed button. Lastly, you could use one button that toggles it on and off, set `aria-live="polite"` on it, and change the text from "Turn on fan" to "Turn off fan" and vice versa.

```js
let fanStatus = 'off'
on.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (fanStatus === 'off') {
    rotateMe.classList.remove('paused')
    rotateMe.alt = 'spinning bladed fan'
    on.disabled = true
    off.disabled = false
  }
})
off.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (fanStatus === 'off') {
    rotateMe.classList.add('paused')
    rotateMe.alt = 'bladed fan'
    on.disabled = false
    off.disabled = true
  }
})
```

```css
img {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
}

.rotate {
  animation: rotate 0.75s infinite linear;
}
.paused {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<img
  src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcScQe7tlEzE58so4n8IIn3LjKI2JCq_HIckHg&usqp=CAU"
  alt="bladed fan"
  id="rotateMe"
  class="rotate paused"
  aria-live="polite"
/>
<button id="on" aria-live="polite">Turn on fan</button>
<button id="off" aria-live="polite" disabled>Turn off fan</button>
```