# How can I rotate an image using only javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript on a site that has a design board so it writes the html for me and I write the js (have no access to anything other than that). I am trying to rotate an image to var degrees onEvent mousemove (I already have var degrees from another part of the game). Is there some sort of turnTo as there is for the turtle? If not is there anything that will rotate the image x degrees?

Comment: It is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51167628/how-to-rotate-image-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I rotate an image using only javascript?

In JavaScript you can use `Element.animate()` where supported. Or alternatively use `requestAnimationFrame` and set the `style` attribute of the element to the relevant CSS values in succession for the duration of the expected effect.